# Order of execution in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {

 private $data = array();
 private $content_data = array();

 public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if (isset($_GET['m2w'])) {
        $stw = switch_to_web();
    }

    if (isset($_GET['w2m'])) {
        $stm = switch_to_mobile();
    }

     // load mobile or desktop view

}


 // Called within an helper function 

function switch_to_web() {
  return set_cookie('load-web', 'true', '86500');
 }

function switch_to_mobile() {
  return delete_cookie('load-web');
}

function is_mobile() {

// return true;
$CI = & get_instance();

if ($CI->input->cookie('load-web'))
    return false;

$CI->load->library('user_agent');
if ($CI->agent->is_mobile()) {
    return true;
}else
    return false;
}
```

I have the above block of code to determine if to load the mobile or web view.

Expected order of execution:

- if m2w is set, set the load-web cookie (this is done before the is_mobile function is called
- is_mobile function sees the load-web cookie has been set and loads the desktop version

Actual order of execution:

- if m2w is set, load-web cookie is called to be set, however the is_mobile function doesn't see it as set hence the desktop version is not loaded
- the cookie is set after the is_mobile function has returned true, i check my browser cookies and observed that the cookie was actually set but not at when expected

What am I not getting right?

Comment: you are showing the class but we need to see the process too.

Comment: just a thought, but you could try a responsive design and not have to bother with this. also, detection through useragents is pretty pointless these days when every browser tries to be almost the same and basically indistinguishable.

Comment: @mamdouh requests are directed to the index.php file that loads necessary code igniter libraries and loads the corresponding controller, I am using the codeigniter framework, in this instance, the constructor is pretty much the entry point unless I am not getting what you mean by the process.

Comment: No no no no - this is not needed "$CI = & get_instance();" as you are extending a controller of CI. You simply use $this->

Comment: @david, I have edited to question to show that the functions were implemented in an helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI's cookies uses the native [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) method of PHP.  Cookies requires to be sent in the HTTP headers before being available in the native `$_COOKIE` variable.

From the PHP doc :

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

Here's the `cookie()` method from CI :

```
function cookie($index = '', $xss_clean = FALSE)
{
    // Simply fetch from the $_COOKIE array and do XSS_Clean if needed.
    return $this->_fetch_from_array($_COOKIE, $index, $xss_clean);
}
```

In short, you set your cookie correctly, but it won't be available until your next request.  It's all because the new value isn't in `$_COOKIE` array.

You have multiple alternatives to fix that.

- You could extend the CI_Input class and modify the `set_cookie` method to also add your new value to the `$_COOKIE` array.
- You could edit your `is_mobile` function to also check for the `$_GET['m2w']` value. (Not just the cookie.)

Personalty, I think the 2nd solution is the cleanest and easiest to do, but I don't know the full scope of your project.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot, that indeed was the problem,i forced a redirect immediately after the cookie is set, what do you think of that approach?

Comment: It's definitively a great approach, especially in the context that you are switching from mobile to desktop or vise-versa.